# Good examples of using sharp package for image operations?

Tags: node.js, image, image-processing, image-resizing, resize-crop

I have been exploring image processing from Nodejs and I came across the Jimp/Lwip/Sharp npm packages. I can do basic operations(scale/crop) on the images using these packages-but looking for good/advanced examples mainly on Sharp package.

Lwip- https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip
Sharp -http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api/

Comment: Have a look at the sharp.io GitHub test cases ( https://github.com/lovell/sharp/tree/master/test )  , they have already implemented many functions. The good starting point to understand framework capabilities.

Comment: This will lead to "opinion-based questions", which does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. Therefore, it must be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The [sharp issue tracker](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues) is a good place to look, they use it for support too. Search for [all issues tagged "question"](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20label%3Aquestion) and you'll get a nice list of sample solutions.